# Populate dropdown with json data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I am trying to populate a dropdownbox with data from a JSON page.

Here is the code I am using:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "json/wcf.svc/GetTax",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: data
        });

        $($.parseJSON(data.msg)).map(function () {
            return $('<option>').val(this.value).text(this.label);
        }).appendTo('#taxList');
    });
</script>
```

And here is what the json data returns:

```
{"d":"{\"16\":\"hello\",\"17\":\"world\"}"}
```

I am getting an error that "data is undefined."  Do I have to somehow tell JQ how to read the json data?

Comment: Where is the "data" variable set?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, the data variable you are passing to the ajax call is not defined (well, not in the code sample you provided), and secondly the ajax call is happening asynchornously, so you need to do something with the returned data, i.e. via a success callback. Example:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var data = //define here
    $.ajax({
        url: "json/wcf.svc/GetTax",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: data, // pass it in here
        success: function(data)
        {
            $(data.msg).map(function () {
                return $('<option>').val(this.value).text(this.label);
            }).appendTo('#taxList');
        }
    });       
});
```

also you shouldn't need to parse the data returned from the ajax call, as jQuery will automatically parse the JSON for you, ( should need the $.parseJSON(data.msg))

**EDIT**

Based on the interesting format of the JSON, and assuming that it cannot be changed, this should work (ugly though)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var data = //define here
        $.ajax({
            url: "json/wcf.svc/GetTax",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: data, // pass it in here
            success: function(data)
            {
                 data = data.d.replace(/{/g, '').replace(/}/g, '').split(',');
                 var obj = [];
                 for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                     obj[i] = {
                      value: data[i].split(':')[0].replace(/"/g, '').replace('\\', ''),
                      label: data[i].split(':')[1].replace(/"/g, '')
                     };
                 }
                 var htmlToAppend = "";
                 for (var j = 0; j < obj.length; j++) {
                     htmlToAppend += '<option value="' +
                         obj[j].value +
                         '">' + obj[j].label +
                         '</option>';
                 }
                 $('#taxList').append(htmlToAppend);
            }
        });       
    });
```

Comment: You are on the right side, but note that `map` returns an array that doesn't have `appendTo` method.

Comment: Thanks, now I can see with firebug the request and response data. However, the dropdown box remains empty.

Comment: if you are getting the response in firebug correctly, perhaps put a breakpoint at the start of the success function to double check that data object is in the format you want, then I would think that the map function isn't doing what you want. Per the small sample of JOSN you provided, there was no msg property in the returned JSON object, so from my point of view the map function will do nothing

Comment: Please note, there is a difference between the $.map() jQuery function and the $('selector').map() jQuery function. The former should be used for processing a plain javascript array or object and consquentially returns the array, and the latter is for a group of match elements from the selector, and returns a jQuery object

Comment: @OJay, I tried changing it to "d' since that is what starts the  json but still no luck.

Comment: Couple of things that just don't seem right. I wouldn't use the .map function, the data returned should already be a javascript object, so I woulud just use a for loop to be honest. Another thing, I think the concept you are going for is that .msg (or .d) should be returning multiple elements, and by the map function you are assuming that each one has a value and label property. Doesn't add up, the JSON idicates a d object, that has one object, with multiple items, I would expect something more like {d:[{16:"hello"},{17:"world"}]}

Comment: I think the root cause of this, is the format that the JSON is in. if the format is identical to what you added in your question (i.e. {"d":"{\"16\":\"hello\",\"17\":\"world\"}"} including all the quotes, and backslashes) then you have a JSON object, that has one property, d, that has a single string value (of "16":"hello","17":"world" ). This JSON is just not well formed, there is nothing to loop over. If you cannot change the way that this JSON is provided, then you will have to parse it with string manupulation (i.e. split on ,(comma) and then split on :(colon))

Comment: I'm using this with a .net WFC service, which apparently adds the 'd' as a security feature.  According to http://encosia.com/a-breaking-change-between-versions-of-aspnet-ajax/, adding a ".d" should take care of things but im still getting a blank box.

Comment: John, added a bit more code to my answer, based on your provide JSON, interested to see it if works

Comment: Yes, the modified code worked.  I am going to look into ASP.NET JSON methods and try to get a cleaner JSON output.  I appreciate the help

Comment: yeah, you should be able to get the WCF service to send a better JSON object. Its almost like the JSON has been encoded twice

Comment: john, just out of interest, this article looks almost exactly like what is happening (bit coincidential I thought) http://encosia.com/asp-net-web-services-mistake-manual-json-serialization/

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `success` option to return the data.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "json/wcf.svc/GetTax",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){

           $(data.msg).map(function () {
            return $('<option>').val(this.value).text(this.label);
        }).appendTo('#taxList');

        }
        });


    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, now I can see with firebug the request and response data.  However, the dropdown box remains empty.